# Updating Angular can not find angular-devkit

Tags: angular, npm

I am getting this error message:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'
See "C:\Users\rashe\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-s9ZG05\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

when I try to run my Angular project with the `ng serve` command. I tried to update angular 8 to angular 9 only to have it break my project. I tried uninstalling angular,npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular, deleting the node module, deleting package.json and package-lock.json, clearing AppData>roaming> npm cache and npm. I did those thing multiple times through npm and manually through my file explorer. I tried updating npm and ng update before and after deleting/reinstalling.I am consistently  getting the same error message. The last thing I tried was uninstalling angular 9 and reinstalling angular 8 but I got the same message. I think it's not version dependent. 
This is what is currently installed:[current angular version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5gom.png)

When I uninstalled angular I did it globally. After, I noticed that although I had Angular cli version 9 the version listed under Angular was 8. So, I deleted/uninstalled everything and when I checked on the Angular cli version it was version 9 but under Angular it was empty. I still had the same error so I deleted/uninstaller everything again and installed Angular cli 8 and currently listed under angular was 8. I don't know if this helps but I thought I should mention it.
My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "dashborad-front-end",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.7",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.1.2",
    "ngx-pagination": "^4.1.0",
    "ngx-take-until-destroy": "^5.4.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.7",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: run npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular and also install npm i @angular/compiler-cli

Comment: Still the same error tried both

Comment: try run npm cache clean --force

Comment: With npm i @angular/compiler-cli i am getting: An unhandled exception occurred: Job name "..getProjectMetadata" does not exist.
See "C:\Users\rashe\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-QNmxEV\angular-errors.log" for further details.

Comment: @PalakJadav error :An unhandled exception occurred: Job name "..getProjectMetadata" does not exist.
See "C:\Users\rashe\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-QNmxEV\angular-errors.log" for further details.

Comment: ok what is your cli version currently? 8 or 9?

Comment: what is @angular-devkit/build-angular  version ?? if you are using angular 8 then you need "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.24",

Comment: 8 you can check the embedded picture for the exact number

Comment: run command  "npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.24"

Comment: I got this when I tried ng serve:`92% additional asset processing scripts-webpack-plugin× ｢wdm｣: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\rashe\OneDrive\Desktop\Dashboard-FrontEnd\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.min.js'`

Comment: try run "npm i jquery"

Comment: I did, right now i am getting typescript errors on everything

Comment: please give error here

Answer (score 0):

The answer is always delete node_modules and npm install again.  also I would clear global entirely and have npm install only run in the app.